# Terraform data source unable to find subnet ids

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to obtain a list of subnet ids from the input below using tags Name.

```
private_subnets = ["private-dev-a","private-dev-b"]

data "aws_subnet_ids" "private_subnet_id" {
 vpc_id = var.vpc_id
 filter {
  name = "tag:Name"
  values = toset([var.private_subnets])
 }
}
```

However I have made sure that I have the subnet with those names even in the Tags and still I get this error.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
│ Error: no matching EC2 Subnets found
│ 
│   with data.aws_subnet_ids.private_subnet_id,
│   on data.tf line 26, in data "aws_subnet_ids" "private_subnet_id":
│   26: data "aws_subnet_ids" "private_subnet_id" {
│
```

Comment: So you are absolutely sure that there are subnets with tag `Name` which equals to `private-dev-a` and `private-dev-b`? Any capital letters maybe? Any other character?

Comment: @MarkoE Yes I am sure that there are Tags with exactly what I am passing

Comment: Can you try the same but with `data "aws_subnets"` instead of this data source?

Comment: @MarkoE its the same. So here is the thing. My variable as you see is picked from a json tfvars file like "private_subnets" :  ["private-dev-a","private-dev-b"]

If  I pass the value directly to the data source it works. So I think something is getting messed up with types here :(

Comment: Well, can you add how that particular part of tfvars file looks like to the question?

Comment: Ah, I've just seen one potential problem: `private_subnets` is already a list, so you don't need to use the square brackets when converting it to a set, i.e., `values = toset([var.private_subnets])` should be `values = toset(var.private_subnets)`.

Comment: Hey @MarkoE thanks for the suggestion. I have tried that as well which dint work. I will check again and update here Thanks again.

Comment: Has anyone solved this problem, today I got the same